# How to properly nest in jade

Tags: html, node.js, pug, template-engine

I am trying to write jade to output the following html:

```
<p class="para">
    This is my post.content.brief text
    <img src="my_image.png"/>
</p>
```

The post.content.brief variable must be escaped properly. Here is what jade I have so far (non-working):

```
p.para
    img(src=my_image.png)
    != post.content.brief
```

The issue is it gives me this html which isnt nested correctly:

```
<p class="para">
    <img src="my_image.png">
</p>
<p>This is my post.content.brief text</p>
```

Comment: Weird, it *should* work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. The post.content.brief variable contained the string `"<p>This is text</p>"`. It was placing it inside another `<p></p>` tag which was causing issues.

To solve the problem all I needed to do was use the following Jade code:

```
div.para
    img(src=my_image.png)
    != post.content.brief
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there are no whitespace characters missing? To get your desired html (as long as post.content.brief doesn't have any tags or anything) it should just be:

```
p.para
  != post.content.brief
  img(src='my_image.png')
```

The reverse works okay for me too:

```
p.para
  img(src='my_image.png')
  != post.content.brief
```

Comment: Your answer works, but I need the img to come before the post.content.brief

Comment: Hmm. It's working for me fine in reversed order too.

Comment: Its something to do with the ! point. When I remove it it nests correctly but my content isn't escaped.

Comment: What version of Jade are you using - `jade -V`? Does your example work from the command line?

Comment: I am using the version that was wrapped in keystone.js . The command line doesn't recognize jade but I dug through the keystone package and found that the jade version is 1.3.1